# Unable to integrate stenciljs component in React application

Tags: reactjs, web-component, stenciljs

I am trying to integrate the web component built using StencilJS but I get the following error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined
    at initializeComponent
```

ReactJS, index.js file =>

```
import {defineCustomElements} from 'my-modal/loader';
defineCustomElements(window);
```

StencilJS component:

```
import { Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() first: string;

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, World! I'm {this.first} <hr />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Any thoughts ? :)

Comment: Added the code snippet :)

Comment: I'm having more or less exactly the same issue - did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Can you post the exact error ? I was able to make it work with create react app than my actual project. Note: You might want to do ``` npm run build --prod``` in the stencil project and do ``` npm link ```.

Comment: I had published a simple component built using Stencil. https://www.npmjs.com/package/my-stencil-project

Comment: Sorry for the delay! create-react-app works for me too. Are you using Parcel by any chance? I'll try what you suggested - thanks!

Comment: Exact error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined at core-b2...`, followed by a couple of errors around being unable to fetch the dynamically imported module.