# import Stencil in Svelte

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, svelte, stenciljs

I have a Monorepo with a svelte project and a Stencil component library. On the [Stencil website](https://stenciljs.com/docs/overview) they very clearly describe how to integrate the library with, for example, Angular

```
import { defineCustomElements } from 'test-components/loader';
defineCustomElements(window);
```

Super easy. But now I would like to use it too in a Svelte project ..... not so super easy anymore :(

When I try to do something similar as described above I get serious errors

[image]

`fbp/dist` is where the Stencil files are.

When I build my Stencil project first and copy my dist into the `public` folder and load  `./dist/fbp.js` in the head of `index.html` it all works. But it would be a lot easier if I could include it similar as it does with Angular. Any suggestions?

Update: Added `emitCss` which gives

[image]

Somewhere at the end it stats: `Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`

UPDATE: With the fixes of @Sambor, Svelte is now able to download the web component, which unfortunately fails

[image]

Comment: what bundler do you use ? (webpack, rollup) ?

Comment: it is `rollup -c -w` all defaults/out of the box so far. If you like you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/scaljeri/flow-based-programming)

Comment: could you try to add this : `emitCss: true,` after line 25 in your rollup config ?

Comment: I've added that property and updated my post. Still not working, but the error is different. It also show this message: `Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new project and I manage to reproduce the same problem.

At first, I was thinking is related to typescript and I've tried bunch of plugins in rollup like : `@tscc/rollup-plugin-tscc, rollup-plugin-typescript` but it didn't work.

I also tried `rollup-plugin-amd` with same results...

Then I've tried to change the main output format and use `es` instead of `iife`.
This way it also required to change the output to a directory instead of file (because of multiple file generation).
And surprisingly this way it seems to work.

here is my code:

/// `index.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='build/bundle.css'>
    <script type="module" defer src='build/main.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note: main.js is imported as module.**

/// `main.js`

```
import App from './App.svelte';

import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from '../my-comp/loader';

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  defineCustomElements(window);
});

const app = new App({ target: document.body });

export default app;
```

/// `rollup.config`

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'es',
        name: 'app',
        dir: 'public/build'
    },
    plugins: [
        json(),
        svelte({
            // Enables run-time checks when not in production.
            dev: !production,

            // Extracts any component CSS out into a separate file — better for performance.
            css: css => css.write('public/build/bundle.css'),

            // Emit CSS as "files" for other plugins to process
            emitCss: true,

            preprocess: autoPreprocess()
        }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')
        }),
        commonjs(),

        postcss({
            extract: true,
            minimize: true,
            use: [
                ['sass', {
                    includePaths: ['./node_modules']
                }]
            ]
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watches the `public` directory and refresh the browser on changes when not in production.
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // Minify for production.
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Note: I took my config from another svelte project (you can ignore uninteresting plugins)

Now it seems to be working fine, but I think is just the starting point :) because there are some known issues with stencil itself which I come across;

```
core-3d1820a5.js:97 TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:57231/build/my-component.entry.js
core-3d1820a5.js:863 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxied' of undefined
```

https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/464

https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1981

same with react: [Unable to integrate stenciljs component in React application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078580/unable-to-integrate-stenciljs-component-in-react-application)

This is not the completely working solution, but I thought it may help you for the next steps...

Comment: Thanks, your config seems to work better. But there is no `bundle.js` any more, so I tried to include (in the index.html) the file `main.js`. Now I get in the browser console the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, I wrote a <Note> near my html code; indeed when you use `es` format it generates a `main.js`, so you have to use this in your `index.html` and add `type="module"`, then the import statement should work.

Comment: I did indeed forgot that one. So the import seems right this time, I still get an error as it seems: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "svelte/internal". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't get this error. Could you please update the question with your current rollup config?

Comment: I have the same config as you have (copy-paste). I commited my stuff to [this](https://github.com/scaljeri/flow-based-programming) public repo. In the root run `yarn`, then goto `./packages/fbp` and run `yarn build`. Now you can reproduce in ./packages/svelte` this error

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've managed to reproduce. My first instinct is to say that is related to `lerna` together with svelte. I will se if I can find something. I will let you know if so

Comment: Note that Lerna is a tool on top of Yarn Workspaces, which might as well be the root cause of this issue!

Comment: I have finally found the solution; When running with `Lerna` it seems to work if you don't include deduplication in `resolve` plugin. So, just comment out this: `// dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')`

Comment: Wow, this is truly getting complicated. However, I think when you've solved one problem, an other will arise. Now it cannot load the component file itself, which is lazy loaded. I've added the error at the bottom of my post. This might not be a Svelte issue, but on the other hand, all this does work with angular :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is what it means to try an "imature" framework :) I think now the errors are related to stencil itself. I will have a look if I can do something about it.

Comment: I found a workaround! If you checkout the integration example in a no-framework situation [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript) it becomes super. I published the Stenciljs package to npm and with `https://unpkg.com/@scaljeri/fbp@0.0.1/dist/fbp.js` I included the web components. It is far from ideal for development but at least it works and is simple. If you find a better way please let me know!!

Comment: Hmm, I wrote to stencil slack about this problem last night, but no one answered.. :-| If I will have something I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I’m still having the same issue in 2020. Surprisingly, the webpack template is working fine. Switching to that for now, until this is resolved.

https://github.com/sveltejs/template-webpack